# how to escape special character in a string in oracle(pl/sql)

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, plsql, oracle10g

I have no programming experience in oracle DB (Pl/sql) I need to write a function where I need to escape all these characters `"` (double quotes) `:` (colon) `\` (backslash) in a given string.

I think I can use replace function to replace all these characters `"` with `\"`, `\` with `\\`, `:` with `\:` but I don't know an efficient way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( '\' || ':"', '([\:"])', '\\\1', 1, 0) from dual;
```

Returns:

```
\\\:\"
```

The first parameter `'\' || ':"'` is a stand in for your input string to be escaped. The second parameter `'([\:"])'` is a regular expression matching your characters to be escaped. The third parameter `'\\\1'` is the replacement string: a backslash and the contents of the capture group. The fourth parameter `1` is the starting point in the string to begin replacing; Oracle counts the first character in a string as number one. The fifth parameter is which occurrence of your pattern to replace; `0` means replace them all.